# HTML to SVG conversion?

Tags: conversion, html, svg

I would like to convert some somewhat straightforward web pages (no javascript, minimal CSS) into SVG for archiving. I am wondering if there is a suggested tool or workflow for this conversion?

My current thought is to somehow open the pages in Adobe Illustrator and then export to SVG. However, that "somehow" is a big question mark.  Maybe something like [this](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/illustrator_html5/) will open HTML into Illustrator?

Comment: Just on a side note: Why do you want to convert them into SVG in the first place? What is the point in archiving them that way?

Comment: I need to make many pages of documentation in html available for a constrainted device.  I will not have an html renderer available, but will have an svg rendering engine.  SVG will, hopefully, result in smaller file sizes than just screen shots of html pages.

Comment: More answers on similar question - https://superuser.com/questions/579933/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-as-an-svg-image

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can print it to a vector format like PDF which is in-principle convertible to SVG.

If you print to PDF you can try converting it to SVG using Inkscape and/or http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg.

You can also try printing to PS/EPS and converting via Uniconverter or Scribus. See [Converting from EPS to SVG format](https://superuser.com/questions/198460/converting-between-eps-and-svg-format)

Comment: Problem is that you then get page breaks at impossible places.

Answer (score 1):

I would dig into some kind of text editor and write some XSL, transforming the HTML/XHTML to SVG. Transformation could be done in different ways.

Obviously this requires that your HTML is valid XML - and maybe it could be with some small changes.

One advantage to this approach is that you have 100% control over the result (SVG document). A disadvantage is that it's a little complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tool which gets you from html to pdf.  Then you can step from pdf to svg (which is presumably easier than html to svg directly):
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/