# Opening .cdr in inkscape on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, inkscape

I am trying to open a .cdr file which I got from thingiverse (a RaspBerry Pi case).
I've installed Uniconverter using the steps in the answer by the user lauhub provided here: [How to install Uniconvertor (command-line app) on Mac OS 10.7.2 (Lion)?](https://superuser.com/questions/374818/how-to-install-uniconverter-command-line-app-on-mac-os-10-7-2-lion)

But when I try to open the .cdr file I get this error:

> UniConvertor failed:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/uniconvertor",
>   line 13, in 
>       uniconv_run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/uniconvertor/**init**.py",
>   line 100, in uniconv_run
>       saver(doc, output_file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sk1libs/filters/**init**.py",
>   line 212, in **call**
>       module.save(document, file, filename, options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sk1libs/filters/export/svgsaver.py",
>   line 339, in save
>       saver.Save()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sk1libs/filters/export/svgsaver.py",
>   line 295, in Save
>       left, bottom, right, top = self.document.PageRect() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PageRect'

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a .cdr file as a [CorelDRAW Image File](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/cdr) then perhaps you will be able to open it with [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), or [Inkscape,](http://inkscape.org/en/) a free application that lets you primarily edit vector graphics. Give that a shot and let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Inkscape uses Uniconverter to import CorelDRAW files.